# Swift weak self function retention

Tags: swift, automatic-ref-counting

If I have a closure that references a `weak var weakSelf = self`, can I change that closure to a direct function reference, through `weakSelf`?

```
struct ClosureHolder {
    let closure: () -> Void
}

class ClosureSource {
    func hello() {
        NSLog("hello")
    }

    func createWeakSelfWithinInnerClosureClosureHolder() -> ClosureHolder {
        weak var weakSelf = self
        return ClosureHolder(closure: {
            weakSelf?.hello()
        })
    }

    func createWeakSelfDotHelloClosureHolder() -> ClosureHolder {
        weak var weakSelf = self
        // The code below won't compile because weakSelf is an Optional.
        // Once I unwrap the optional, I no longer have a weak reference.
        // return ClosureHolder(closure: weakSelf.hello)

        // this strongifies the weak reference. :(
        return ClosureHolder(closure: weakSelf!.hello)
    }
}
```

Instead of `createWeakSelfWithinInnerClosureClosureHolder`, I'd prefer something like `createWeakSelfDotHelloClosureHolder`.

Comment: What are you trying to do here that isn't handled by [closure capture lists](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID56)?

Comment: I didn't know about closure capture lists. I think this may have inspired a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't. Saying `self.foo` (if `foo` is a method) is exactly the same thing as to saying `MyClass.foo(self)`. And methods curried in this fashion always keep a strong reference to the receiver object. If you want to maintain a weak reference, then you need to stick with the `{ weakSelf?.hello() }` approach.